# How do you call the relation between these 2 variables?

Tags: terminology

Let's say I have an X number and I want to increment it by 50%, I would get

$X*A=Y$

Then in order to multiply Y and get X again I would need to do

$Y*Z=X$

How do you call the relation between A and Z?

Example with numbers:

$$5*1.5=7.5$$
$$7.5*Z=5$$
$$Z=0.66$$

How do you call the relation between 1.5 and 0.66 when $X*1.5*0.66=X$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A and Z are multiplicative inverses; i.e., A × Z = 1.

Therefore, X × A × Z = X

Usually, we just say that A is the inverse of Z (and vice-versa).

Comment: I prefer 'reciprocal' to _just_ 'inverse', but 'multiplicative inverse' is the most specific and least ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between both definitions?

Comment: In my experience (BS in math from a US institution) 'reciprocal' and 'multiplicative inverse' are more-or-less equivalent. The term 'inverse' by itself, without the word 'multiplicative' attached, carries a lot of mathematical baggage in that it is used for many different things. Function inverses, inverses of binary operators (addition, multiplication, Fourier transform, etc), inverse mappings, etc. Hence why I prefer 'reciprocal' or 'multiplicative inverse' as they are unambiguous and don't require context to understand.

Comment: @Fraaaan: There are many kinds of inverses: matrix inverse, trigonometric inverse (for example arcsine is the trigonometric inverse of sine but is not defined as 1/sine) etc. But generally `reciprocal` refers to multiplicative inverse. However, note that in some fields like engineering and physics there could also be many different concepts that have the name `reciprocal`